# Copying content for only odd numbered lines using bash

Tags: bash

i have a file containing:
`0x0003ffff` (line 1 ,col 2)
`0x0003ffff` (line 2. col2 )
`0x0000ffff` (line 3, col2)
`0x0000ffff` (line 4, col 2)
There can be 'n' number of such lines but will start from col 2 only.

I want to copy the the content of line 1 and paste it in line 35 col 9 of another file 'lc.txt'
Similarly i want to copy the content all odd numbered lines and paste it in a specific line and column of some other file one by one.

How can i do that using bash scripting?

Comment: Getting the right numbers out the input data is trivial by comparison with the problems involved in 'pasting line one at line 35, column 9' of another file.  One problem is 'what is the formula for where line N, col 2 goes in the other file'; another is 'does the new value get inserted before whatever was in the column of the other file, or does it overwrite what was there'; another is 'is what's already there the same size as the replacement' (it gets to be quite a bit more difficult if the old and the new are different sizes).

Comment: Can you post the complete sample input/output data?

Answer (score 1):

The following will extract odd-numbered lines.

```
awk 'NR%2' input.txt
```

The pasting to a separate file is not well specified.  Maybe you want to open a separate question about that.  But perhaps something like this;

```
sed -e "35s/^........./&$(awk 'NR%2' input.txt)" otherfile.txt
```

Comment: Upvoted the standalone awk command. The sed+awk is a bit iffy at best but then again the question could mean just about anything :-).